# Download a video from twitter using status URL without API also Soup object is not expanding

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, download, blob

Hey guys I am trying to download a video from twitter without using twitter API in Python and I am facing two problems, first one is that when I am trying to extract data using Beautiful Soup my Soup object is just not returning anything. 2nd is that I have seen that videos in twitter use "blob" and I can't figure out how to get this blob URL and then how to get the correct source of the video from this blob URL. Please help and thnx in advance.

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
URL = "https://twitter.com/ananyapandayy/status/1270339195672752129"
HTML = req.get(URL).content
Soup = BS(HTML)
print(Soup)
```

[image]

Comment: The link to image for an idea of what I am saying is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKVK7.png

Comment: You will not get any link to download the video via direct URL like that except you listen to data stream via pupeeteer, check https://apitester.com/# and put ur url there, I'm sure and learn what it's ouput. Why not bother using Twitter API?

Comment: Well I know that it's possible I just don't know how, now for why am I not willing to use API is because it requires tokens which are time consuming, complex and makes it harder to transfer my code to my friends, hope u get my point.